# get all date values between two times in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1:

```
empid           DT
9999    2018-10-23 19:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-24 07:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-22 06:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-24 03:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-24 05:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-23 06:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-23 21:00:00.000
```

Table 2:

```
emp_id           in_time              out_time
9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000   2018-10-22 06:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-22 06:00:00.000   2018-10-22 07:00:00.000
9999    2018-10-23 19:00:00.000   2018-10-24 07:00:00.000
```

I tried this query to get all data in table1 between intime and outtime from table2 but i cant able to get in between these in_time and out_time

```
select a.emp_reader_id, DT, EVENTID1
from trnevents a 
left outer join daily_attendance_data d on d.emp_reader_id = a.emp_reader_id
left outer join employee e on e.emp_reader_id = a.emp_reader_id
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), A.DT, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-23', 23) 
       and CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), A.DT, 23) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-24', 23))
  and a.emp_reader_id=9999
group by a.emp_Reader_id, a.dt,a.eventid
order by emp_reader_id, DT asc
```

> Expected Output:
>       in_time:2018-10-23 19:00:00.000
>       out_time:2018-10-24 07:00:00.000

```
2018-10-23 19:00:00.000
2018-10-24 03:00:00.000
2018-10-24 05:00:00.000
2018-10-24 07:00:00.000
```

Comment: Why are you converting your dates to a `varchar`? Treat your dates as what they are, a `datetime`.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? (SELECT DISTINCT?)

Comment: i ant in between particular dates and  all data between that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if DT is datetime then below where condition will work no need any varchar conversion

```
where DT>='2018-10-23 19:00:00.000' and DT<='2018-10-24 07:00:00.000'
```

Comment: thank you.. but i tried this (A.DT >=d.in_time and  A.DT <=d.out_time) it takes value from before time.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7f450e49b1fa1348f5a1fe1d9f13498f @TimeAttendanceSystem does it solve your problem